# Amazons Alexa: requests are not shown in the voice history

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, avs

I wrote a webserive like echosim.io or sammachins webalexa etc. Im able to record a question, send it to alexa and get an answer. But the requests are not shown in the voice history.

How does this history work? When i talk to alexa via echodot or echosim my requests/responses are shown in the history. How can i enable this function for my product.